# Prevent projected texture rotation on moving of SpotLight target

Tags: three.js

I'm exploring new feature of three.js r144 - texture projection for SpotLights. Unfortunately I didn't succeed in creating of a working example using CodePen or JSFiddle, but the whole scene is quite simple. The light source and its target are put into an Object3D (light container) which is located in the center of a square room. The light source projects some texture towards one of the walls with little offset along horizontal axis. Now if we start to rotate light container around that axis, we can notice that the texture projection also rotates while approaching to positions when the light source looks strait up or down. Here is a couple of screenshots to help to understand how it works:

[image]
*Here everything is almost fine. The texture projection has some distortion because the light source is shifted to the right.*

[image]
*Here is the problem: the light source looks almost vertically up and the texture is rotated.*

Is it possible to prevent texture rotation somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I applied quaternions of pitch and yaw objects to the original up vector of the shadow camera:

```js
// Save original up vector on light initialization
const shadowCamera = this.light.shadow.camera;
const upOrigin = shadowCamera.up;

// Update up vector in render loop
const pitchObjectQuat = this.pitchObject.quaternion; // Pitch object is direct parent of the light
const yawObjectQuat = this.yawObject.quaternion; // Yaw object is direct parent of pitch object
shadowCamera.up.copy(upOrigin).applyQuaternion(pitchObjectQuat).applyQuaternion(yawObjectQuat);
```